If Odd-Odd nuclei can have a range of spin-parity, what makes it choose a certain value?
For example, Al-28 has an unpaired proton in $1d_{\frac{5}{2}}$ and an unpaired neutron in $1d_{\frac{3}{2}}$ (please correct me if I'm wrong here). Applying jj coupling tells us that the nuclear spin parity could take values J=$1^+, 2^+, 3^+, 4^+$. If experimentally the nucleus has a spin-parity of $3^+$, what makes this particular value preferential?

preferential spin-parity minimizes nuclear energy through the residual interaction between unpaired nucleons' angular momenta, as seen in Al-28's J=3+

The unpaired proton in the 1d5/2 and the unpaired neutron in the 1d3/2 interact via their magnetic and spin-orbit coupling. The strongest interaction occurs when their total angular momentum couples to J=3+

@Joshua question comments are for comments, e.g.: requests clarification, not answers. Your 2 comments are an answer, so cut-n-paste them into answer. That way 1) OP can accept and answer an move or 2) you can get your points.
